# Why do i get "forEach is not a function at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload" error?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to use riot api but keep getting for.Each is not a function error. Can you guys help me ? My Js Code :

```
const app = document.getElementById('resultContainer')
const results = document.createElement('div')
results.setAttribute('class', 'results')
app.appendChild(results)

var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', 'https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lor/ranked/v1/leaderboards?api_key=APIKEY', true)
request.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response)    
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        data.forEach((players) => {
          const results = document.createElement('div')
          results.setAttribute('class', 'results')
    
          const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
          h1.textContent = players.name
    
          const p = document.createElement('p')
          rank = players.rank.substring(0, 300)
          p.textContent = `${players.rank}...`
    
          results.appendChild(card)
          results.appendChild(h1)
          results.appendChild(p)
        })
      } else {
       console.log('Error')
      }

}
request.send()
```

console.log of data is

```
data: {players: Array(1155)}
```

Comment: Short answer is the response is not an array, it's an object apparently. `forEach` can only be used on `Array`s

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

Because when you parse the response as `JSON` it creates an `object`, not an array.

You need to use `forEach` on the `players` property of that object, i.e `data.players.forEach`